# How to make UIImagePickerController works under switch case UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 UIImage *tempImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 imgview.image = tempImage;
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [picker release];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [picker release];
}


-(IBAction) calllib
{
 img1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 img1.delegate = self;
 img1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
 [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES];

}

all the codes above works well for taking out photos from the photo library.
problem is that when i tried to use it under the UIActionSheet it does not work.
i just copy the lines of codes from the -(IBAction) calllib as follow.


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 UIImage *detectface = [Utilities detectFace:imgview.image];
 UIImage *grayscale = [Utilities grayscaleImage:imgview.image];
 UIImage *avatars = [Utilities avatars:imgview.image];

 img1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 img1.delegate = self;
 img1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

 switch (buttonIndex)
 {
  case 0:
   [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES];
   imgview.image = detectface;
   break;
  case 1:
   [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES];
   imgview.image = grayscale;
   break;
  case 2:
   [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES];
   imgview.image = avatars;
   break;

  default:
   break;
 }

}
```

it does not work. can somebody help me to figure out what is the problem?

the switch case works perfectly without the [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES]; ...

thanks

Comment: the switch case works! but only if i have an image on UIImage. the problem now is, after i have selected a case the codes seems like running together at the same time. it will change the image then only goes to the photo library.

Comment: what do you actually want to do? I don't understand your switch case

Comment: that switch case is actually triggered by a button. for each case it will do different function. for case 0, it will detect the face.. and so on.. what i wanted it to do is before the face detection works, it will go to the photo library first to select photo.

Comment: oh so, you cannot do it like this, it is not the correct way

Comment: what's the problem? can u help me out? thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 img1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 img1.delegate = self;
 img1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

 switch () {
   case 0:
    [self presentModalViewController:img1 animation:YES];
 }

 – (void)imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:SOME_KEY_HERE];
    imageView.image = [Utilities detectFace:image];

 }
```

you need to call the detect face after you get the image, which means in the delegate method returned from UIImagePickerController

Comment: but i want it to be in all of the 3 cases.. how should i code it for all of the 3 cases when all of it do different function..

Comment: :) , i got it ady.. i declare a global variable for the buttonIndex n pass it to the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function. as following..

Comment: - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 a = buttonIndex;
 
 img1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 //pass event to self
 img1.delegate = self;
 
 //call photolibrary
 //source type selection.. for whole
 img1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

 [self presentModalViewController:img1 animated:YES];

}

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 UIImage *tempImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 imgview.image = tempImage;
 
 UIImage *detectface = [Utilities detectFace:imgview.image];
 UIImage *grayscale = [Utilities grayscaleImage:imgview.image];
 UIImage *avatars = [Utilities avatars:imgview.image];

Comment: switch (a)
 {
  case 0:
   imgview.image = detectface;
   break;
  case 1:
   imgview.image = grayscale;
   break;
  case 2:
   imgview.image = avatars;
   break;
   
  default:
   break;
 }
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [picker release];
}

Comment: sorry for the comment i replied.. its messy.. im still new here at stackoverflow.. really wanna thank you for the hint.. thank you very much :) it works perfectly

Comment: ah, can you vote up my answer or accept my answer by ticking in the V mark in the left under the 0 score?